# UnSupportedClassVersionError after adding a library

Tags: android, class

I created a simple java project and added a jar from [APK LIBRARY](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)
after add

adding library cause  `UnSupportedClassVersionError`  and and when i remove that library from my project that error won't go till i re create my project.

but if i run Main method in jar from command line . This library works fine

Comment: which jdk version are you using for your app?

Comment: ok i found another problem, if i run empty project with jdk 6.0 it gives UnSupportedClassVersionError  error but if i run my empty project with jdk 5.0 it gives no error, but if i add library it gives error The java class could not be loaded. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (brut/androlib/res/util/ExtXmlSerializer) bad major version at offset=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse check the compiler compliance level and change it to 1.6 for the project and libraries.

Comment: or right-click the project and select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties